# Python: How to get else statement to run x number of times?

Tags: python, telnet, ping, cisco

I have a script to telnet router and if it can't ping 8.8.8.8 to reboot router, but I don't want it to reboot the router more than three times in a row.
If it fails to ping 8.8.8.8 after three times I want it to keep pinging 8.8.8.8 until it comes back up again and start all over again.

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.call('ping 8.8.8.8', shell=True)
while output == 0:
output = subprocess.call('ping 8.8.8.8', shell=True)
else:
import telnetlib
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

host = "912.168.1.1" # your router ip
username = "name" # the username
password = "password"
filename_prefix = "cisco-backup"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
tn.read_until("Username:")
tn.write(username+"\n")
tn.read_until("Password:")
tn.write(password+"\n")
tn.write("reload"+"\n")
tn.write("y"+"\n")
enter code here
```

I'm only new at this and I don't know how to get the else statement to only repeat three times in a row.

Comment: You need a loop after the `else`.  However, there is little point in having an `else` on a `while` loop if you don't have a `break`.  The `else` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing indentations, so I hope I got your logic right, anyhow the following should do what you want.

In your case there is little sense in using the else statement because that will only put you in a position where you have to create another while loop. Another fix is moving the `output = subprocess.call...` line to the end of the while loop, after the router has been reset (if you entered the loop, it is clear the router if not responding, no reason to try again before reboot).

I added the `retries` variable to keep track of how many times the router have been reset and added it as a condition to the while loop. If retries exceed 3 times the loop will break.

```
import subprocess
retries = 0
output = subprocess.call('ping 8.8.8.8', shell=True)
while (output == 0 and retries < 3):
    import telnetlib
    import datetime

    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    host = "912.168.1.1" # your router ip
    username = "name" # the username
    password = "password"
    filename_prefix = "cisco-backup"

    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
    tn.read_until("Username:")
    tn.write(username+"\n")
    tn.read_until("Password:")
    tn.write(password+"\n")
    tn.write("reload"+"\n")
    tn.write("y"+"\n")
    output = subprocess.call('ping 8.8.8.8', shell=True)
    retries += 1

if (retries == 3):
    print ("Couldnt restore router")
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try doing this:

if I understood correctly, what you are trying to do is to make a script the will continuously try to ping 8.8.8.8 and if it fails it will reboot the router (at most 3 times) if the rebooting didn't help the script should ping 8.8.8.8 until it succeed. after that the script will start all over *again*.

```
import subprocess
output = 0
while output == 0:
    output = subprocess.call('ping 8.8.8.8', shell=True)

    for i in xrange(3): #will restart the router until ping works OR at most 3 times

        if output == 0:  # if the ping succeeded don't restart the router
            break

        import telnetlib
        import datetime

        now = datetime.datetime.now()

        host = "912.168.1.1" # your router ip
        username = "name" # the username
        password = "password"
        filename_prefix = "cisco-backup"

        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
        tn.read_until("Username:")
        tn.write(username+"\n")
        tn.read_until("Password:")
        tn.write(password+"\n")
        tn.write("reload"+"\n")
        tn.write("y"+"\n")

        output = subprocess.call('ping 8.8.8.8', shell=True) #after restarting the router check the ping again

    #after the loop
    while output != 0: output = subprocess.call('ping 8.8.8.8', shell=True)  #will ping until the ping work
```